Clone Workspace SCM plugin implementation through pipeline in jenkins
I am converting jenkins freestyle jobs to pipelines. I have clone_worksapce_scm_plugin installed through which we are copying workspace of a specific project as scm. How can I implement this in pipeline code?
I tried the following:

cloneWorkspace(String parentProject, String criteria = 'Any') -> this gave an error saying "No such DSL method found"

Tried with copy artifacts plugin to copy everything from workspace -> This took a lot of time and increased build duration.


Are there any better alternative ways to make this work?

I am not aware of any drop-in replacement. In general workspaces should be treated as ephemeral resources. Once a run has completed you shouldn't rely on its workspace being available. If you have something in your workspace that you need to reuse and it's something large your best option is to zip it up and upload to some storage (S3, Azure Blob, what have you).
